# Spring MVC 4 display an error message

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to display and error message if there was an error logging in and I cannot figure out how to do it. This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView getLoginForm(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    model.addObject("user",new User());
    model.setViewName("login_form");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    User loggedInUser=userService.getUser(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword());
        if(loggedInUser==null) {
            ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");
            model.addObject("errorMessage","Invalid Login");
            return model;
        }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users");
}
```

The errorMessage is null in the jsp. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're performing a redirect.

Comment: yes. is there a better way to do it? I am new to spring mvc

Comment: Model attributes are just request attributes. Request attributes are bound to a single request. You're responding with a 302 response and your client is making a new request. Those attributes don't exist on the second request. Use flash attributes as shown in the duplicate.